# Laravel Redirect doesnt work in my function

Tags: laravel, function

I have a function. If I click on this function, the user should be activate or deactivate.

I tried different things, but my code doesnt work.

```
public function deactivate($id)
    {
        $user = User::find($id);
        if ($user->verified == 1){
            $user->verified = 0;
            $user->save();
            $angebot = Angebot::where('firma', $id);
            $angebot->delete();
            return redirect('/admin')->with('success', 'Nutzer wurde erfolgreich deaktiviert');
        }

        if($user->verified == 0){
            $user->verified = 1;
            $user->save();
            return redirect('/admin')->with('success', 'Nutzer wurde erfolgreich aktiviert');
        }

    }
```

this is my function in my controller

and this is my view:

```
<a href="{{ route('admin.deactivate',$user->id)}}"> @if($user->verified === 0)
                            <button class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fas fa-eye-slash"></i></button>
                            @else <button class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fas fa-eye"></i></button>@endif</a>
```

and this is my route:

```
Route::get('admin/{id}', 'AdminController@deactivate')->name('admin.deactivate');
```

this are my other routes:

```
Route::resource('admin', 'AdminController');
```

if i do php artisan route:list i got this

Domain | Method    | URI                        | Name             | Action                                                     | Middleware                                      |
+--------+-----------+----------------------------+------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+
|        | POST      | _ignition/execute-solution |                  | Facade\Ignition\Http\Controllers\ExecuteSolutionController | Facade\Ignition\Http\Middleware\IgnitionEnabled |
|        | GET|HEAD  | _ignition/health-check     |                  | Facade\Ignition\Http\Controllers\HealthCheckController     | Facade\Ignition\Http\Middleware\IgnitionEnabled |
|        | GET|HEAD  | _ignition/scripts/{script} |                  | Facade\Ignition\Http\Controllers\ScriptController          | Facade\Ignition\Http\Middleware\IgnitionEnabled |
|        | POST      | _ignition/share-report     |                  | Facade\Ignition\Http\Controllers\ShareReportController     | Facade\Ignition\Http\Middleware\IgnitionEnabled |
|        | GET|HEAD  | _ignition/styles/{style}   |                  | Facade\Ignition\Http\Controllers\StyleController           | Facade\Ignition\Http\Middleware\IgnitionEnabled |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin                      | admin.index      | App\Http\Controllers\AdminController@index                 | web                                             |
|        | POST      | admin                      | admin.store      | App\Http\Controllers\AdminController@store                 | web                                             |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/create               | admin.create     | App\Http\Controllers\AdminController@create                | web                                             |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/{admin}              | admin.show       | App\Http\Controllers\AdminController@show                  | web                                             |
|        | PUT|PATCH | admin/{admin}              | admin.update     | App\Http\Controllers\AdminController@update                | web                                             |
|        | DELETE    | admin/{admin}              | admin.destroy    | App\Http\Controllers\AdminController@destroy               | web                                             |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/{admin}/edit         | admin.edit       | App\Http\Controllers\AdminController@edit                  | web                                             |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/{id}                 | admin.deactivate | App\Http\Controllers\AdminController@deactivate            | web                                             |
|        | GET|HEAD  | api/user                   |                  | Closure                                                    | api,auth:api                                    |
+--------+-----------+----------------------------+------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+

does anyone know whats wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your route has some extra ***(id*** right after *AdminController@deactivate* which is not needed, please review and remove from your code, or edit your if it's just a typo in your question.

Comment: Is it doing anything or giving you an error? Also try forcing the if statement to type specific '===' comparison

Comment: Do you have this route '/admin' defined?

Comment: it goes to the page /admin/2 (id) but in my function it has to do the redirect

Comment: do you know why?

Comment: do you have the index method, there is where your redirect should land